# Share comments in Google+ communities

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-plus, share

I am using Google+ to share the comments in my google+ profile in my iOS app and it is working fine. Now i want to share the comments in Google+ community like [this](https://plus.google.com/communities/112026628790708717979). How can i do that, any help?